# Is PHP OpenSSL library completely isolated and in no way linked with any OpenSSL binary on Ubuntu

Tags: php, openssl

We are using OpenSSL library provided by PHP. But does this PHP OpenSSL library internally uses OpenSSL binaries that are probably provided as pre-compiled binaries with Ubuntu OS ? Just putting in a doubt.

Just want to know that PHP OpenSSL library is completely isolated and in no way linked with any OpenSSL binary on Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - this is fairly obvious from the package lists. As with all other elements in Ubuntu, the PHP version (by default) is tied to the Ubuntu version, and the same rules apply to PHP as for any other `.deb` package.

- For [`php8.1`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/php8.1-common) (Ubuntu 22.04),  `libssl3` is the system-wide `libssl`.
- For [`php7.4`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/php7.4-common) (Ubuntu 20.04),  `libssl1.1` is the system-wide `libssl`.

If you installed PHP as a normal `.deb` package, then the dependency is shared with all other packages on the system.

On the other hand, if you installed PHP inside a container, then it would include its own dependencies, including `libssl`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Artur , is it same for PHP7.4.32